# Computing pi by using definite integral of a circle

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to coding, and my assignment requires that I approximate pi by using the definite integral of area of a disk (circle) with radius 1. I have created the following code, via Python. This gives me the correct answer, however pi is truncated to six digits. Is there a way for me to expand it to 7 digits, per assignment parameters? Thanks so much!

Code: 
GlowScript 2.7 VPython

```
x=-1
dx=0.00001
A=0
while x<1:
    A=A+sqrt(1-x**2)*dx
    x=x+dx
tpi=2*A
print(tpi)
```

Comment: `print "{0:.7f}".format(tpi)`

Comment: Why do you use Python 2.7 ? It is not a bad version but it is deprecated, if you are learning consider Python 3.

Comment: When I use that command, it sends: Unexpected token: string «{0:.7f}»: Any way to get around this? Appreciate the help

Answer (score 0):

What you see in the console does not always match the value of a variable. The console might cut of some digits (a logger usually does this in order to save space on the screen) or the python interpreter might round. To combat this you can use the following code to extend the number of digits

```
# coding: utf-8
import math
x=-1
dx=0.00001
A=0
while x<1:
    A=A+math.sqrt(1-x**2)*dx
    x=x+dx
tpi=2*A

print("{0:.30g}".format(tpi)) #this will give you 30 digits including the digits before the . !
```

Comment: Thank you! When, I add that in, prior to the print command, it issues "bad --lines option: .20g"

Comment: Well, I forgot that you used python 2. I adjusted my code. Should run on 2.7

Comment: Why don't you use python 3? I am seriously asking myself why so many people still use python 2.

Comment: Thank you so, so much. The import math function indicates what, again? Apologize again, first time completing a coding assignment, and my professor specifically requested 2.7.

Comment: try to talk to your professor about python 3! It is important that you don't use outdated tools. import is a way to tell python that you want to use a module. A module holds functions and data that we want to use. think of it like a file that holds a bunch of functions and classes for you. Since we want to use the sqrt we need someone how provides it for us. Mathe has a sqrt function we can use, so we import it. My environment needed that to work.

Comment: As far as I know python 2.7 support ends in the year 2020. Python 3 is around since 2008. While python 2.7 is still a good tool, it won't be around forever.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you're using Python version 2.7? Try to format the float when you're printing the value:

```
print('%.7f' % tpi)
```

This should print your value as a float rounded to 7 decimal places. To read more about that, have a look at [String Formatting Operations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting)